# using vue script setup with cdn

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

do we have a way to write compostion api script setup with cdn like this?

```
<template>
{{message}}
</template>

<script setup>

 message:"welcome"; 



</script>
```

I searched for it but found no solutions I used it in vue 2 and it is available in vue 3 options api but is there anyway to do the same in script setup? Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you use it with CDN? Vue SFC and script setup in particular should be compiled. It's not valid JS otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but this will work ([playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpNTkkOwjAM/IrlM03uVanEP3IpkSmtmkWxSw9R/k5SEOLm2TyT8Rajeu2EPQ5CLm6T0Gg8QM7giHmaCUoxftB/aoVs0xIFmGSPp98Gz/KLXMHgQZsNjgy29Mc/4gUXF0OSzk1RrRx8Lc4tb74CG+zhZBpXlzVs8CkSudeaH7bNXVmFNOt6qbR7WRwpYtfdUziYUn3cWgHq8ILlDQtVT+c=)):

```html
<template>
  {{ message }}
</template>

<script setup>
  const message = "welcome"
</script>
```

I recommend you to read [the Vue Composition API faq](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html).

Comment: have you tried it using the vue cdn link?  using the cdn link it don't work like this. but if you use the vue installation then it works.

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>